# SourceTree - Delete a pushed and merged commit

Tags: git, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I've seen some topics about deleting commits and so on but nothing worked so I'm asking here.
Me and my friend were working on our project, he pushed a commit and I pushed a commit but when we merged there were problems. Turns out we edited the same script at some point.

I just want to delete that merge, the **"it says it has conflicts"**. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout master then force push your local master branch to origin/master

```
git checkout master
git push origin master -f
```

This will force the master branch on origin to point to the commit with the message "Made the crafting..."

SourceTree intentionally makes it pretty hard to force push to prevent you from "deleting" commits.